# сравнить char* с++

Tags: c++, строки

Запутался немного. Как сравнить параметр вызова программы char* ?

```
 int main(int argc, char* argv[])
 {
  string key ="77";
  if (argv[1]==key) cout << "верно" << endl;
 }
```

Comment: int strcmp(const char *str1, const char *str2). Прототип: string.h.

Comment: по любому условие не выполнится

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Класс `string` содержит метод compare, возвращающий 0 если строки равны:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    string key ="77";
    if (!key.compare(argv[1]))
        cout << "верно" << endl;
}
```

Comment: И почему это лучше, чем `operator==`?

Comment: @int3 потому что у автора один операнд ```std::string``` а другой ```char*```, не существует такой перегрузки по умолчанию, однако вы можете перегрузить ```operator==``` самостоятельно, если в этом есть необходимость

Comment: такая перегрузка [существует](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp) (8). И я **не могу** перегрузить его самостоятельно, это UB.

Comment: @int3 можете, сделайте это в своем namespace и не получите UB. По поводу перегрузки - да, не знал о такой, однако автор в ответе указал такой пример и его это чем-то не устроило.

Answer (score 4):

Да именно так, как вы и сравниваете. Класс `string` обеспечивает сравнение с использованием оператора `==`.

Второй вариант - если бы вы сравнивали непосредственно литерал `"77"` - с использованием функции сравнения С-строк `strcmp`:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  if (strcmp(argv[1],"77")==0) cout << "верно" << endl;
}
```

P.S. Только убедитесь, что `argc > 1`, а то `argv[1]` будет нулевым указателем - как-то некрасиво окажется обращаться туда, куда нельзя :)